# Use dots in Docpad topic file names without getting warnings?

Tags: docpad

I have a topic file with a version number in it, it is called `dummy-v1.2.3.html.md.eco`. When rendering this, I get warnings:

```
info: Welcome to DocPad v6.59.6 (local installation: /export/suppoweb-src/docpad/node_modules/docpad)
info: Contribute: http://docpad.org/docs/contribute
info: Plugins: cleanurls, coffeescript, downloader, eco, highlightjs, less, livereload, marked, partials, related, stylus, text
info: Environment: static
info: Generating...
warning:
  Rendering the extension "html" to "3" on "release/topic/dummy-v1.2.3.html.md.eco" didn't do anything.
  Explanation here: http://docpad.org/extension-not-rendering
warning:
  Rendering the extension "3" to "2" on "release/topic/dummy-v1.2.3.html.md.eco" didn't do anything.
  Explanation here: http://docpad.org/extension-not-rendering
warning:
  Rendering the extension "html" to "3" on "release/topic/dummy-v1.2.3.html.md.eco" didn't do anything.
  Explanation here: http://docpad.org/extension-not-rendering
warning:
  Rendering the extension "3" to "2" on "release/topic/dummy-v1.2.3.html.md.eco" didn't do anything.
  Explanation here: http://docpad.org/extension-not-rendering
info: Dumped 253 files to the database cache
info: Generated 248/253 files in 26.555 seconds
info: The action completed successfully
info: Shutting down... cya next time!
INFO - web-driver.sh: done
```

I know I can avoid this by using a different naming scheme (eg `dummy-v1-2-3.html.md.eco`). However, is it possible to get Docpad to ignore the version number as rendering extensions?